# What are these errors about in the Chrome console when visiting StackOverflow?

Tags: support

Console output:

> GET http://static.adzerk.net/ados.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>   (index):3630
>
> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket
>   handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade': Keep-alive
>   full.en.js?v=9240c8d6318e:16
>
> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please
>   use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:3
>
> WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not
>   'Upgrade': Keep-alive

I think the event.returnValue is because of JQuery (rite?) but what are the other errors? Does anyone else see them like is it a bug?

[image: Screenshot of Chrome's console.]

Comment: That looks like an adblocker doing its job.

Comment: @3ventic If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. That was the issue.

Comment: `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` - this is the key phrase in your error. It is the client (that's you) that has blocked a resource. As @3ventic correctly suggested - it's most likely some extension or plugin is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually four separate errors / warnings:

- The first one, as noted, appears to be caused by an ad-blocker extension doing what it's designed to do: the page tried to load some JavaScript code from adzerk.net to display ads, but the extension blocked it.
- The second and fourth ones are SE's WebSocket code flaking out.  I honestly don't know why it's failing, but I'm seeing a lot of it myself, too.  Fortunately, it seems to be harmless, since the Stack Exchange JS framework will fall back to ordinary AJAX calls if it can't use WebSockets.
- The third error (actually, a deprecation warning) comes from this expression inside jQuery:

  ```javascript
  a.defaultPrevented || a.returnValue === false ||
      a.getPreventDefault && a.getPreventDefault()
  ```

  It's checking to see if an event handler has asked for the default behavior of the event to be suppressed, either by calling `.preventDefault()` on the Event object or by returning false.

  In fact, the code *does* try to check the standard `.defaultPrevented` property first, and only falls back to the old and deprecated `.getPreventDefault()` method if it can't find it.  Unfortunately, as written, it doesn't differentiate between the `.defaultPrevented` property being *missing* and it simply being *false*, so the deprecated method still ends up being called for any events whose default behavior has *not* been prevented.

  This bug seems to have been [fixed in jQuery 1.11](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14282), where the code looks like this:

  ```javascript
  // Events bubbling up the document may have been marked as prevented
  // by a handler lower down the tree; reflect the correct value.
  this.isDefaultPrevented = src.defaultPrevented ||
          src.defaultPrevented === undefined && (
          // Support: IE < 9
          src.returnValue === false ||
          // Support: Android < 4.0
          src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ?
      returnTrue :
      returnFalse;
  ```

  However, Stack Exchange is still using old jQuery 1.7(!), so we'll be stuck with this warning for a while yet.